# From Matlab to the web

Tags: java, apache, matlab, web, matlab-deployment

I have big project in Matlab with some pretty complicated GUI. I'd like to put it on my apache server. The idea is: people should've access to it without downloading anything (I mean something like Java applet or web app). I've managed to create a .jar file by using the deploytool but I'm not sure it's the right way. I've read mathworks tutorial, but in the example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/javabuilder/ug/bsqrikz-26.html they're using some piece of JavaCode which I don't really know where they got it from. In the end I've created a .war file but the apache sees it only as an archive, not as an application, so clearly I did something wrong.

So, could someone tell what I have to do step-by-step to create a web application from my Matlab code, please?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of webinars by MathWorks showing how. Here is the most recent one I could find:

> [Application Deployment with MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/application-deployment-with-matlab-81715.html)

For reference, there is a [page](http://web.archive.org/web/20111219140917/http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1608.html) listing all the options for [deploying MATLAB on the web](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/compiler/example_guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. In this tutorial the guy's saying that I will need to design the user front-end. How to do this? As I said the GUI in my app is complicated and I need exactly the same interface on my website. Is there a fast and clever way to convert it from matlab (I mean from what's in the .fig file) to an applet-like application? Or do I have to do it all manually?

Comment: @Adam: you will have to design the inteface manually using Web technologies (HTML, CSS, Javascript).

Comment: Couldn't you just have the whole GUI could be deployed as a single java component? Then you'd only have to use CSS to position the GUI as a whole. Or am I missing something...

Comment: @Amro: The link you posted seems to have been moved. Any chance you can update this answer? I suspect http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/ might be to something similar, but since I don't know what you linked to originally, I can't tell!

Comment: @chrisb2244: thanks for pointing out the broken links, it's fixed now. You could also search for related videos at: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/index.html or http://www.mathworks.com/company/events/webinars/index.html, the website has hundred of videos on various topics.